# htaccess. Everything to index.php one level in. Works except what I want to redirect to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

#### Situation

I am trying to redirect all my traffic to the index.php file one level above root, for example:

```
lala.com/this/who/
lala.com/this/knew/it
lala.com/this/hello/
lala.com/this/would/be/so/annoying
```

This and it works using the rules defined below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /this/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php? [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Problem

The above works without issue but...If I try going to

```
lala.com/this
```

I get sent back to lala.com. Can someone please offer me a quick pearl of wisdom here. Thank you kindly for reading my question

#### Attempt

I have tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/this
RewriteRule ^this - [L,NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to the RewriteBase whitch is defined to /this/. Try this modification :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ this/index.php? [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: awwwww, i feel like such an idiot. That did solve the problem thank you very much. Strongly feel i should pay much more attention to htaccess